# Drawing text with PIL does not work on all images

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to draw text on images with PIL. However, I can see text on certain images only. A lot of png's don't work, such as this one:

http://r0k.us/graphics/kodak/kodim16.html

Code sample:

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from os.path import expanduser


im1=Image.open(expanduser('~/Desktop/in.png'))

# Drawing the text on the picture
font = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Songti.ttc', 100)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im1)
draw.text((50, 600), 'OMG!', fill="#aa0000", font=font)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im1)

# Save the image with a new name
im1.save(expanduser('~/Desktop/out.png'))
```

I've tried adding `.convert("RGBA")` and using RGB for colour, to no avail.

The code works on the photos taken from my iPhone. But when I use `ImageMagick` to convert those iPhone photos to .jpg or .png, the code stopped working again.

Is it that this text-drawing feature only works on certain image formats?

**UPDATE**

I added the actual text position to the `.text()` call. The code works on .png taken from iPhone.

Comment: You haven't set `textpos`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I actually did. Let me add all the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just got the `x` and `y` coordinates the wrong way around and were trying to write 600 pixels down an image that is 512 pixels tall:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

im1=Image.open('start.png')

# Drawing the text on the picture
font = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Herculanum.ttf', 100)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im1)
draw.text((50, 200), 'OMG!', (255,0,255), font=font)

# Save the image with a new name
im1.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: OMG! So the api allows you to draw outside of the canvas?

Comment: Yes, try changing the coordinates to `(50,480)` in my code.

Comment: Got it! What a surprise. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Excellent! In my case what happened is that the image was so big that the text showed so small and I thought it was not being written down.